# Error in starting rviz

Tags: rviz, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! When I try to start rviz by "roslaunch rviz rviz", I see this message:

```
... logging to /home/ros/.ros/log/8b43025e-7aa4-11e2-89df-080027387536/roslaunch-ros-VirtualBox-3363.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

Can you help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55632/error-in-starting-rviz/) by [vitkt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4234/vitkt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz is a program, not a launch file. Try it this way:

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4